# Fix parent field value when using django multi-table inheritance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models

I am trying to build a django interface to help with the management and provisioning of resources within our company infrastructure. I am trying to use polymorphism with the concept of "Resource Providers".

## Scenario

Here are some stub models that would represent the scenario well:

### Resource Models (provided by one app):

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    """
    Representation of the physical resource
    """
    pass
```

### Abstraction for resource providers (provided by a second app):

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    """
    Representation of a service provider that can provide resources
    """
    id = models.SlugField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)


class ResourceProvider(models.Model):
    """
    'Abstract' class for a provider of the resource represented by Resource
    """
    provider = ForeignKey(Provider, null=False)
    provides = ForeignKey(ServerImage, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('provider', 'provides')
```

### Individual resource provider (provided by many apps - one per provider)

```
class ServiceResource(ResourceProvider):
    """
    Representation of the resource on a particular
    """
    service_identifier = models.UUIDField(null=False)
```

## The questions

### How can the individual apps register as a provider?

Each app that provides resources should be identifiable via some id. This registration should take place in the `Provider` model and will then be used by `ServiceResource` as the `provider` field.

I probably could call `Provider(id='some-provider').save()` at the top of the `models.py` file but I don't feel this is the best way to do it, causing the table to be updated every time the `models.py` is loaded.

Another way would be manually adding a line to the migrations file, but I feel like this is wrong and a little bit hacky. There may be a django way of doing this that I haven't yet discovered. I expect there probably is a 'correct' way of pre-populating tables.

### How do I make it so that the ServiceResource always uses the apps respective provider value?

The three ways I can think are:

1. Declare it as part of the object (don't think this will work as this will mask `provider` with a `Provider` instance rather than creating a ForeignKey which references `Provider(id='service-provider')`

`class ServiceResource(ResourceProvider):
    provider = Provider(id='service-provider')`

2. Set it while initialising the object. Although not recommended I could override the `__init__` method and set the value there/add it to the `**kwargs` before passing to the parent constructor.
3. Create a static method that creates the object - this feels like it would be a little less guaranteed and that people could break the expected format. Would the django admin use this?

## Closing

I hope what I am trying to achieve makes sense. If I can provide any more detail or example, or if anything is unclear, post a comment and I will reply or update the question.